# revtex-4.1 no bibliography

Tags: bibtex, revtex

I have exactly the same problem as: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65477/trouble-generating-bibliography-in-latex-using-revtex-4, but there is no solution ://

Does someone know how to solve it? My os is gentoo-linux, I have installed revtex from repository.

Comment: Post a simple example of your problem, so we can help you.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: Like I wrote, the problem is the same like in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65477/trouble-generating-bibliography-in-latex-using-revtex-4. I have a simple tex file and at the end of file I want to add my reference list by use of a ref.bib file:          \nocite{*}
\bibliography{ref}% Produces the bibliography via BibTeX. On the pdf-output there is no list of reference. That is exactly the same problem as described in the link which I have attached.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It is considered a lot better to put in some code that will compile, as it makes it a lot easier for us to copy it into our text editor and work with it, and see exactly what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: Ok, so here is my tex file: http://paste.org/56379 and here is by .bib file: http://paste.org/56380.

Comment: I guess that you need the `numerical` option.

Comment: OK, that is it!! Thank You:)) I will mark my question as "solved"

Comment: @egreg Please write a short answer or cast a closing vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `numerical` option, which, differently from the other options regarding the bibliographical references, typesets a reference section. With the default option for `aip` you get references in footnotes.

```
\documentclass[
 aip,
 jmp,
 amsmath,amssymb,
% preprint,
% reprint,
% author-year,
% author-numerical,
 numerical
]{revtex4-1}
```